# MSSQL Localdb проблема с ограничением поля NVARCHAR

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-localdb

Существует таблица категорий:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[categories] (
  [id] INT IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
  name          NVARCHAR(128) NOT NULL,
  parent_id     INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  position      INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,  
  deleted       BIT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0, 
  is_default    BIT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  question      NVARCHAR(256),
  title         NVARCHAR(256), 
  description   NVARCHAR(512),
  filter_name   NVARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
  parent_style  NVARCHAR(64),
  date_create   DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT GETDATE(),    
  PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([id] ASC));
```

При попытке вставить данные:

```
INSERT INTO categories(name, question, title, description, parent_id, filter_name, parent_style) 
VALUES ("Курьерские услуги",                
        "Ищете быстрого и надежного курьера?",              
        "Нужен курьер на несколько доставок",               
        "Например: необходимо доставить 10 небольших пакетов (общий вес не более 7 кг) по 5 адресам. Желательно успеть развезти пакеты за один день.",
        0, "courier", 'fas fa-rocket'); -- #1
```

Возникает ошибка:

> Msg 103, Level 15, State 4, Line 6
>   The identifier that starts with 'Например: необходимо доставить 10 небольших пакетов (общий вес не более 7 кг) по 5 адресам. Желательно успеть развезти пакеты за' is too long. Maximum length is 128.

Однако длина поля description = 512, да и вообще в моей таблице цифр таких нет, как 128 :)

Объясните что откуда растёт, пожалуйста...
Всем большое спасибо за ответы.

Comment: SQL Server ожидает строки в одинарных кавычках. А вы ему передаете в двойных.

Comment: @Разработчик Адильханов, очень интересная таблица категорий!!

Comment: @Yaroslav спасибо. А почему она интересная?

Comment: @Adilkhanoff, я таблицу категорий себе проще на много представляю, а у Вас она какая то специфическая!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Когда вы пишите `"Курьерские услуги"` ваш сервер ищет переменную(колонку) с таким названием. И похоже, что нельзя создавать переменную длинной больше 128 символов.

Правильно обрамлять строчки надо в одинарные кавычки, например так `'Курьерские услуги'`

Comment: Все проще, он пытается вставить все в первую колонку из-за неверно выбранных ковычек.

Comment: @NickProskuryakov если бы он пытался вставить все в первую колонку, он бы не ругался что не может преобразовать ""Например: необходимо доставить 10 небольших пакетов.." в идентификатор.

Comment: @Viktorov есть. Теперь с кодировкой проблемы... Вставляю "Курьерские услуги" сохраняет "?????? ????????"

Comment: @Adilkhanoff это уже другая проблема. Создайте для нее отдельный вопрос